# Odd CoreData Memory Leaks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, memory-leaks

When final testing my application in Instruments for leaks, I come across 2 odd leaks:

Leaked Object: _PFArray,     #: 1   Address: 0x2a11c0   Size: 32 Bytes  Responsible Library: CoreData Responsible Frame: newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT

And

Leaked Object: Malloc 16 Bytes,     #: 1    Address: 0x24d6b0   Size: 16 Bytes  Responsible Library: CoreData Responsible Frame: newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT

The stack traces for both leaks point to:

```
records = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] retain];
```

in a CoreData Fetch.

And

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

What are these leaks? I have never seen them before. They do not pop up when I build and Analyze. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks!!

**EDIT:**

Here is the code around the records array. Records is just an NSarray declared in the .h.

```
  /*
 Fetch existing events.
 Create a fetch request; find the Event entity and assign it to the request; add a sort descriptor; then execute the fetch.
 */
marblebeingdragged=YES;
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Child" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

// Order the events by creation date, most recent first.
NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *prizeDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"prize" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *neededDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"marblesneeded" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *colorDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"color" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *reachedDiscriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"prizereached" ascending:NO];



NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:nameDescriptor,prizeDescriptor,neededDescriptor,colorDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[nameDescriptor release];
[colorDescriptor release];
[prizeDescriptor release];
[neededDescriptor release];
[reachedDiscriptor release];
[sortDescriptors release];

// Execute the fetch -- create a copy of the result.
NSError *error = nil;
records = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] retain];
```

Comment: Are you releasing that retain after you are done?

Comment: @whitelionV I do release records in the dealloc method of my MainViewController.

Comment: I think you don't have to `retain` the fetched result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to release the "records" object. And you need to release it after you are done using it, NOT in dealloc method. Post more of your code. How did you define records? Post the entire core data code block please if you want any help.

```
records = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] retain];
//.... code using records
[records release];
```

Edit:

Either use this

```
records = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]]; // no retian
```

OR this

```
records = [[[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] retain] autorelease];
```

Comment: I have added the entire block of code. Also, the records array is edited and saved to core data throughout my entire application. It should only be released when the view is closed. Thanks

Comment: No i am interested in records object. Is it a retained property in .h file? is that the first place where you are allocating? anyways try to add autorelease at the end and see. it should solve the problem since i dont have visibility to the relevant portions of your code. Or remove the retain and try self.records = [[self.managed ...

Comment: The records array is declared as such: `@property(strong, nonatomic) NSArray *records;`

Comment: And you failed to mention that you are using ARC when you are asking a question on memory leakage!

Comment: I am not using ARC. When switching strong to retain, the same leaks appear.

Comment: did you remove the retain or try autorelease?  also use self.records

Comment: When I release records after the fetch, the leaks go away!! Is it okay to release it then if it is called in other methods(swiping the screen)? Should I use autorelease, if so how?  Thanks!

Comment: I edited the response. Please accept the answer if it solves your mem leak

Comment: Don't I need to release the autorelease pool?